# When does piston start to experience resistance in gas filled blocked tube?

Tags: pressure, acoustics

Imagine a tube with piston at one side,filled with gas in middle and wall at other side.Very similiar to piston in engine.

When the piston starts moving forward,it will push the gas forward,the pressure change starts to propagade down the tube at the speed of sound.Imagine that the dead end/blocked end/wall is 34 cm away down the tube away from the piston.

If the speed of sound inside the gas between wall and piston is 340 m/s,that means it will take 1 milisecond until the propagating pressure change hits the wall.Until then the process happens as if the tube was infinite and there was no wall at other side.

My question is this,when does the piston moving forward starts to experience resistance due to the blocked end? I see two points when it might start happening,either at 1 milisecond or 2 milisecond.Lets consider that the piston moves forward so little that its change in position over time can be ignored.

It can either be 1 ms becose that is the time it takes sound to reach the wall.

Or 2 ms becose that the time it takes for sound to travell to wall and back to piston.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movement of the piston will experience an effect of the wall at the end of the tube when the pressure wave reflection from the wall returns to the piston.